# Cannot use gnupg: Error 117

Tags: encryption

The plugin gnupg (https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg) worked fine until recently where I get the error:

```
# vim myfile.asc
Error detected while processing BufReadCmd Autocommands for "*.{gpg,asc,pgp}":
E117: Unknown function: gnupg#init
```

**What would be the origin of this error and how can I make gnupg plugin work?**

Comment: check that the plugin is correctly installed

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> E117: Unknown function: gnupg#init
> ```
>
> What would be the origin of this error?

Vim is trying to run a function named `gnupg#init()` that it will look for in a file named `autoload/gnupg.vim` under directories listed in [`'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27).

Functions with a `#` in their name are [autoloaded](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#autoload).

Looking at the vim-gnupg plug-in source code, it [clearly provides this function](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg/blob/f663d0e857bd88cb39c16ca45c37a27488648562/autoload/gnupg.vim#L75), so this *should* work.

> and how can I make gnupg plugin work?

Check that your plug-in installation actually includes this file `autoload/gnupg.vim` and the function `gnupg#init()` inside it. You might want to consider reinstalling the plug-in to make sure it is.

Check that the plug-in's base directory is listed in `'runtimepath'`. That option is typically managed by your plug-in manager, so make sure this plug-in is properly configured with your plug-in manager so that it will properly register it under `'runtimepath'`.

Vim might be having some trouble reading or parsing the `autoload/gnupg.vim` file, check the output of the `:messages` command inside Vim to see if Vim reported other errors before this one that might point to the root of the issue.

Comment: Other things: `scriptnames` (and the scriptease equivalent, `Scriptnames`) help when tracking down loaded scripts. I find `new | put =split(&rtp, ',')` to be helpful. P.S. `#` functions don't have to be autoloaded (I've seen some plugins do this... it irks me, but it's technically fine.)